# string concatenate in Html anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I created cluster.js file and inside that one base url variable created ex.

```
var path ={
  projectName:"http://localhost:8080/UniconnectConfigurationWeb"
};
```

Now i want to set path.projectName whenever i need to use this basic url instead to write whole url. But problem is when i concatenate path.projectName with "/cluster" following unexpected url link open. ex. http://localhost:8080/UniconnectConfigurationWeb/path.projectName+%22=/cluster%22.

How can i concatenate base url with some string in html/jsp anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

> use this

```
<td class="formtext"><a href="http://localhost:8080/webtop/drl/objectId/'"+object_id+"'>View</a></td>
```